# Why do I get segmantation fault when using pointer to structs in fucntions?

Tags: list, c++11, struct, nodes

Im a beginner coder trying to create a simply linked list using structs nodes in c++. Below is my code trying to establish a simple function which is supposed to add nodes/data and connect them to an existing previous node.

It compiles just fine, but when I try to run it I get segmentation fault.

Im sure it's something silly that I haven't taken into account yet.Any help/guidance is deeply appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>


//singly linked list using struct node


void add(struct node *);


struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};



int main()
{
    struct node *head;
    struct node *conductor;

    struct node a;

    *head = a;
    *conductor = a;

    add( conductor);
}

void add(struct node *conductor)
{
    conductor->next = NULL;

    std::cout << "What is the data?\n";

    int x;

    std::cin>> x ;

    if (x == -1) {
        return;
    } else {
        conductor->data  = x;

        conductor->next = new struct node;

        conductor = conductor->next;

        add(conductor);

        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger and get a backtrace from the position of the segfault. Also, just use `std::list`. And please format your code properly. And `main()` returns `int`. Have you got any C++ book or tutorial at all?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Some more information about what/why/how you're trying to accomplish, and what you've tried so far, would be helpful.  There are [some tips here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about posting questions.

Comment: @underscore_d  
I'm still new to this and I dont think the returning value of main() plays any role in this case. I'd appreciate some help on my use of pointers though.

Comment: I don't care if the return type plays any role. It makes your code invalid if you don't specify it, and it would be irresponsible of readers not to point that out, possibly leaving you to release malformed code into the wild.

Comment: @underscore_d
Noted.

Comment: Hint:  *head = a;  is wrong, maybe  head=&a; is your intention!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like as [Kyle Gunnar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1004756/kjell-gunnar) suggested in the comment you have a problem with:

```
*head = a;
*conductor = a;
```

Lets investigate what is happening here.
This kind of action, assigning a struct/class with another instance, Is actually triggering an **assignment operator**. Without defining any it will invoke a **default assignment operator** which should be sufficient in this case.

The problem is, to have this kind of behavior working you need to have a valid instance to the left of `=`.

In this case you have an uninitialized pointer to the desired struct. And by dereferencing it (using `*`) you try to access an **unallocated memory**, which is illegal and throws **segmentation fault**.

It seems like the quickest solution will be:

```
head = &a;
conductor = &a;
```

Again as suggested by [Kyle Gunnar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1004756/kjell-gunnar)